# Timeline JS Multiple Photoview?

Tags: jquery, timeline.js

In TimelineJS, is it possible to select a photo on the timeline so that it pops out into a carousel so a user can view multiple photos (akin to how photos are viewed on Facebook)?

Comment: A question asking "is it possible" is often not a good question for StackOverflow, because anything is possible.

Comment: I actually really appreciate this comment. It gave me another idea of how I could do this. Thank you, stranger.

Comment: Hey, sometimes all you need is encouragement.  Once you get a working example, you should answer yourself here so it helps others in the future.